# Is $f(x)+\sum_{p,i=1,...,m}\lambda_{p,i}x_{p,i}(x)$ globally defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Is the map $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{N\cdot m}\times M\ni (\lambda_{p,i},x) \mapsto  f(x)+\sum_{p}\sum_{i=1,...,m}\lambda_{p,i}x_{p,i}(x)\cdot \phi_{p}(x) \in \mathbb{R}$  globally defined, 
where M is compact smooth manifold, $x_{p,1},...,x_{p,m}\ $ are local coordinates,$\phi_{p}$ are partition of unity for chart at p and f $\in C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$?

Are there any well-defined problems in the intersection of coordinate charts covering M? Since M is a manifold ,the coordinate charts will agree on the intersection.

This is for proving Morse functions are generic.

Comment: There is a problem. If $y\in M$ is not in a local coordinate $(x_p)$, what is the definition of $\Phi$?

Comment: Where is this question coming from? This seems pretty unmotivated.

Comment: @John I meant a double sum i.e. a)running over all the charts (finitely many since compact) and b) running over each coordinate.

Comment: So the y will be in one of them.

Comment: @TKM: So what is the definition of $x_{p,i}(y)$ when $y$ is not in that coordinate?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to add that we multiply by partition of unity functions. That must fix the problem.

Comment: Then that will be fine. Each $x_{p,i}$ is well defined on the local coordinate and $x_{p,i} \phi_p$ is well defined on $M$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to multiply by partition of unity functions. That fixes the problem of making it globally defined.